# Python random.Random(bytearray) TypeError: unhashable type

Tags: python

In Python3, random.Random(seed) allows to seed using a bytearray.

```
class Random(_random.Random):
    ...
    def __init__(self, x=None):
        self.seed(x)
        ...

    def seed(self, a=None, version=2):
        ...
        if version == 2 and isinstance(a, (str, bytes, bytearray)):
            if isinstance(a, str):
                a = a.encode()
            a += _sha512(a).digest()
            a = int.from_bytes(a, 'big')
        ...
```

When you try

```
>>> random.Random().__init__(bytearray([1, 2, 3]))
```

or

```
>>> r = random.Random()
>>> r.seed(bytearray([1, 2, 3]))
```

it will work without exception.

But when you try this, the result is inconsistent.

```
>>> random.Random(bytearray([1, 2, 3]))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'bytearray'
```

I compiled and debuged python 3.7.0 binary, when tried to init a PRNG with a bytearray, it will invoke `random_seed` method in Modules/_randommodule.c and directly raise a typeerror here. Why?

Comment: first option you create an instance called ```r```. The last example you don't..

Comment: `random.Random(x=bytearray([1,2,3]))` works. (Python 3.6.7, Linux, and I get the same error as you with `random.Random(bytearray([1,2,3]))`.) This is weird.

Comment: In Python3,  `bytearray` is considered as `bytes`. So try to used `bytes`.
`random.Random(bytes(bytearray([1, 2, 3])))`

Comment: What about this way `random.seed(bytearray([1, 2, 3]))`
`print (random.random());`

Answer (score 2):

The exception doesn't come from the `Random.__init__()` method but from the `__new__()` method, which is called before `__init__()`:

```
>>> random.Random.__new__(random.Random, bytearray([1,2,3]))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'bytearray'
>>> random.Random.__new__(random.Random, bytes([1,2,3]))
<random.Random at 0x1b0cd78>
```

Answer (score 1):

[BlackJack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53765831/10776965) enlightened me. I read the [C source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_randommodule.c#L435) of the `_random.Random.__new__` method carefully.

The `_random.Random.__new__` method (`random_new` in C) invokes `_random.Random.seed` method (`random_seed` in C) with the same arguments. If the `args` in the `random_seed` function contains a non-int object as a seed, it will try to [get the hash value](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_randommodule.c#L268) of the object. So it will raise a type error when the object is a bytearray.

Thus, `_random.Random` doesn't specially handle seeding with a bytearray but its subclass `random.Random` did, which seems like an incompatible python bug.